# Config issue in Laravel 5.1.20

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My site looks perfect in localhost but when I migrated to Production server it display below error:

```
The use statement with non-compound name 'Config' has no effect
```

I have used my config variable in my view file like this:

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('content')
    <section>
    <?php
    use \Config;
    ?>      
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="<?php echo Config::get("app.images_url")?>assets/data/icon-s1.png" alt="service">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </section>
@stop
```

Localhost:
Laravel 5.1.20 and PHP version 5.5.9

Production:
Laravel 5.1.20 and PHP version 5.5.30

Comment: Is that error shown in the browser or the error log? Because if it's shown in the browser it begs the question: **Why do you have debug mode enabled in production?**

Comment: No I have seen this error on error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class without declaring it first. So remove the `use \Config` first and them add this in `src`:

```
{{ Config::get('app.imagss_url`) }}
```

You should use blade tags instead of PHP when you can.

Comment: The "\" is not really needed, as views are not namespaced.

Answer (score 2):

This error arises in later versions of PHP due to the use of a non-compound namespace in non-namespaced code.

Basically, while you're in the root namespace, PHP complains if you access something in the root namespace using a fully-qualified namespace.

To fix it, you can do one of the following things:

1. remove `use \Config;`
2. change `use \Config;` to `use Config;`
3. use [Service Injection in Blade Templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection)
4. inject the path value into your blade template from the controller (thus eliminating a reference to the config class in your template completely)

The best solution is probably the last one. Templates are intended to be for display only - pass in the values you want to display and don't introduce any logic. That keeps your code more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a helper method in Laravel 5 called `config`

You could use it like so:

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('content')
    <section>   
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="{!! config('app.images_url').'/assets/data/icon-s1.png' !!}" alt="service">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@stop
```